# Storing prop:values in Array, still returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

While going through array, I came to this strange code snippet.

1. arrays are different from objects so how can they store value in `prop:value` format?
2. Even if they did, then why `arr[3]` returning undefined?
3. Can someone tell me is there any name for these kind of arrays? or their practical use case?

[image]

Comment: arrays are objects, so you can add properties if you want - in your example, you have arr[0], arr[1] and arr[2] and arr.abc ... no arr[3] ... how your particular browser (probably chrome) decided to show that `abc` prop is confusing you

Comment: Arrays, being objects, can have arbitrary properties assigned to them, for the most part, just like properties can be assigned to ordinary functions - it's just not a very good idea, since it's confusing and isn't what arrays are designed for. The property is named `abc`, so access it via `.abc` - it's not a numeric property, so `[3]` doesn't work.

Comment: One of the exceptions is: regular expression matches produce arrays of type RegExpMatchArray, which have non-array properties on them. Having arbitrary key-value properties on an array isn't forbidden, just *usually* a code smell.